# Formal statement that functions intersect

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation

How do I express the following as a mathematical statement with quantification of all variables and making the universe explicit.

"The curves $y=1-x^2$ and $y=3x-2$ intersect"

So far I have $(\exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{R})$

Comment: How would you say that a point $(x,y)$ is on one of the curves?

Comment: Hint: if a point belongs to both lines (i.e. they intersect), then it's abscissa will give the same ordinate when substituted into the lines' equations.

Comment: Ahh right, if both are true. under the original condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to even mention the irrelevant $y$:

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}\ s.t. 1-x^2 = 3 x-2$$

Just for "culture," here is a graph confirming there are two solutions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x\in \mathbb{R},\, \exists y \in \mathbb{R},\,\,y=1-x^2 \,\wedge\, y=3x-2$$

Comment: Thank you, but wouldn't this also suffice $(\exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{R},y=1-x^2 \wedge  y=3x-2$ )

Comment: Isn't this statement redundant? It's sufficient to state that there exists an $x$ for which $1-x^2=3x-2$. Correct?